# Deleting A Node From A Singly Linked List -- Using MALLOC/FREE

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, malloc

I'm writing the oh-so common methods of deleted a node from a singly linked list, but I'm unsure if the way I'm deleting them (by using FREE()) is correct. I want to truly delete the node and free up the memory. I have provided the strut definition for Node as well as how Node structs are created.

I understand in Java anytime nothing is pointing to data, it is cleaned up automatically. I figured for C, I have to use free, but am I using it correctly? For example below, when I 'free' current, am I able to make current reference something else after? What is the best way to do this?

Thanks and I hope my question is clear!

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

struct Node* newNode(int value) {
    struct Node* node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (node == NULL) {
        // malloc fails. deal with it.
    } else {
        node->data = value;
        node->next = NULL;
    }
    return node;
}

void delete(int value, struct node *head) {
    struct Node* current = head;
    struct Node* previous = NULL;

    while (current != NULL) {
        if (current->data == value) {
            if (previous == NULL) {
                current = current->next;
                free(head);
            } else {
                previous->next = current->next;
                free(current);
                current = previous->next;
            }
        } else {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. When you use `free` and provide a pointer, the data in which the pointer is currently pointing to is freed in memory. The pointer itself is stored elsewhere and can be used to point to different data post 'freeing'. You are correct in creating a link between the previous and next nodes when deleting a non head node (`previous->next = current->next` and `current = previous->next`).

One addition I would suggest to your code is that after freeing `head` you should reassign the head pointer to the new head post deletion, which in this case would be current.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help, using `free()` command

```
struct Node
{
     int data;
     struct Node *next;
}
Node* Delete(Node *head, int position)
{
  Node *temp1 = head;
  if(position==0){
      head = temp1->next;
      free(temp1);
      return head;
  }
  Node *temp2;
  while(position>1){
      temp1 = temp1->next;
      position--;
  }      
  temp2= temp1->next;
  temp1->next = temp2->next;
  free(temp2);
  return head;
}
```